# How $(r-k){r \choose r-k}$ becomes $r{r-1 \choose r-k-1}$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I'm reading Knuth/Graham/Patashnik's Concrete Mathematics:

> [image]

I don't understand how he goes from $(r-k){r \choose r-k}$ to $r{r-1 \choose r-k-1}$ using $(5.6)$. The mentioned property has a $k$ in one side and an $r$ in the other. I'm confused at what I should do. I'm using the RHS of $(5.6)$, and $r$ is $r$, then what would be the $k$ in the other side and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(5.6)$ states:
$$
\color{green}{k} \binom{\color{red}{r}}{\color{green}{k}} = \color{red}{r} \binom{\color{red}{r} - 1}{\color{green}{k} - 1}
$$
So, in this case:
$$
(\color{green}{r - k}) \binom{\color{red}{r}}{\color{green}{r - k}} = \color{red}{r} \binom{\color{red}{r} - 1}{\color{green}{r - k} - 1}
$$

---

To answer your question directly, the "$k$" in $(5.6)$ is simply $r - k$ now.

Comment: Simply apply $(5.6)$ with "$k$" substituted by $r - k$. If it makes it easier for you, try rewriting $(r - k)\binom{r}{r - k}$ as $p \binom{r}{p}$ with $p = r - k$, applying $(5.6)$, and then going back.

Comment: Hey, I've finally been able to understand it. I've posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

- Using the symmetry:

$\displaystyle(r-k){r\choose k}=(r-k){r\choose r-k}$

- Now using $(5.6)$:

$\begin{eqnarray*}
  {(r-k){r\choose r-k}}&=&{(r-k) \frac{r}{r-k}{n-1 \choose n-k-1}} \\ 
  {}&&{}\\
  {}&&{}\\
  {}&=&{\frac{(r-k)r}{(r-k)} {n-1\choose n-k-1}} \\
  {}&&{}\\  
  {}&&{}\\
  {}&=&{r{n-1\choose n-k-1}}
\end{eqnarray*}$